# Jquery grid data binding from SQL server

Tags: jquery, grid

How can I populate jquery grid from SQL server?

Answer (score 1):

You should specify more details to get a better response.

However, you cannot call SQL Server from JQuery just like that. You need a Web Service or a WCF Service that will handle the database call (eg. via ADO.NET), and then the service operation can return a JSON result to your JQuery client. Once you have the JSON result you can bind it to any view (DataGrid table, List etc.)